# Calculating a moving average over a changing window

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, moving-average

This is a really complicated problem for a total newbie. I can't give the whole subroutine either. It seems to be working except for the part where I calculate the average. I have used a whole slew of the solutions I found here, though none do what I need them to do.

```
ave = WorksheetFunction.Average("C" & i, "C" & j, "C" & k, "C" & l, "C" & m, _
            "C" & n, "C" & o)
```

Where ave is a long, and i - n are integers, calculated based on the value of i.

I just need to take the average of the specified cells and place the result into cell Ei. I can't get the calculation to work (nothing happens, not even an error), so I haven't bothered with placing the result yet. But if I could get help with that too, it would be great.

Thanks!

*Edit - This particular code is throwing me error 1004. But when I used

```
Range("E" & i) = Worksheet...
```

It was doing nothing. No results, no errors.

*Edit2 - I have it working now, thanks! Here's the code that works.

```
ave = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C" & i).Value, Range("C" & j).Value, _
                Range("C" & k).Value)
Range("E" & i).Value = ave
```

Comment: What does "*I can't get it to work*" mean?  That tells us nothing.

Comment: Literally, nothing happens.

Comment: did you checked the value of ave? whats the value of ave?

Comment: The value of ave should be the result of the calculation.

Comment: I know it should be. but whats the actual value?

Comment: Ohhhh, sorry. When I "watch" ave while stepping through the program, it is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ave = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("C" & i).Value, Range("C" & j).Value,..ect)
```